# Python: how does this translator replace letters

Tags: python, algorithm, uppercase, lowercase

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiouy":
            if letter.upper():
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation
print(translate(input("Enter A Phrase to Translate: ")))
```

I'm just learning python and following a tutorial and I don't understand this code. So this is a basic translator that makes all vowels "G", the for loop picks every letter in a phrase that the user enters and checks if it is a vowel, what I don't get is after it finds the vowels, it adds g to the translation, how does this work, if your trying to replace the vowel why does adding g to the entire thing translate it?

Comment: When will `letter.upper()` *not* be considered True?

Comment: @ScottHunter never. I ran it on my own computer and `asdf` turned out to be `Gsdf` instead of the supposed `gsdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is here:

```
        if letter.lower() in "aeiouy":
            if letter.upper():
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
```

If the letter is a vowel, then it adds a g *instead of* the supposed vowel (`translation = translation + letter` won't be executed).

Also, since `letter.upper()` doesn't check if it's lowercase (it just turns the character into uppercase), `translation = translation + "g"` will never be reached- maybe replace `letter.upper()` with `letter == letter.upper()`?

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for an hour and you cleared it up very well, I also fixed the issue with letter == letter.upper()

Comment: @anoor1234 Glad to help. Please upvote/accept my answer if this was helpful.

Comment: Btw, there is also `letter.isupper()` which returns a `bool` and should be equivalent, at least for alphabetical characters.